# Why doesn't React retrieve data or errors from a GraphQL query, even though the API is executed when skip is true?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, apollo-client

I have a query that needs to be executed when I click on a button. To achieve this, I've set skip to true so that I can manually trigger the query using refetch. However, even though I can see the query being executed in the network tab as expected, I'm not receiving any data or error as a result. Both the data and error variables remain undefined. I'm unsure why this is happening and what steps I should take to resolve it.

Here you can see how I have used the query from @apollo/client.

```
<button onClick={handleFetchData}>Fetch Data</button>
```

```
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";

const { loading, error, refetch } = useQuery(GET_CARD_DETAILS, {
  variables: {
    confirmationId,
    name,
  },
  skip: true,
});

const handleFetchData = () => {
  refetch();
};
```

Comment: Do you get the data if you remove skip? And can you confirm that you are actually sending the required variables in the network tab? You can use a plugin for chrome called "Graphql Network Inspector" to get all the info that graphql returns

Comment: Yes, if I remove skip and send the request I can see the data or errors as per the case. But I want to skip the initial fetch as at that time I don't have the required variable data.

Comment: Does it work if you use skip with ```notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true```? If that doesn't work, try using ```useLazyQuery``` instead of ```useQuery```. I had a weird bug in my apollo client where the error response never triggered or resolved on specific npm version. Maybe updating it will solve the issue